# Format number with + and - sign

Tags: wpf, binding, formatting, integer, string-formatting

I have some WPF textblocks in a stackpanel that I want to databind and format.

E.g. the following formats a date 24h style without the seconds part:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCustomObject, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" />
```

Now, I would like to bind an integer and also display the + and - sign (i.e. +6 or -4).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyOtherCustomObject, StringFormat={}{0:+#}}" />
```

This however, does not work. 
Is this possible or do I have to write a complete converter just for this?

**EDIT**

Nikolays post led me to the answer:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyOtherCustomObject, StringFormat={}{0:+#;-#;''}}" />
```

In essence you provide a format for positive numbers, negative numbers and an optional part what to do with zero. In this case I stated that a zero should be displayed as an empty string.

Regards,

Michel

Comment: The answer to this question is only almost correct. See [bug formatting small negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19586067/2712726)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyOtherCustomObject, StringFormat={}{0:+#;-#;''}}" />
```

This article has nice samples of int formatting - http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent link and this leads to: {Binding MyOtherCustomObject, StringFormat={}{0:+#;-#;''}}