# Issue with StringFormat for small negative numbers that have been rounded

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I am trying to write a string format that will round or pad numbers to two decimal places, and also display negative numbers with brackets around them. This is in a in a WPF application, but it applies to any .net StringFormat use case. For example:

- 2.0 -> 2.00
- -2.0 -> (2.00)
- 0.01 -> 0.01
- -0.01 -> (0.01)
- 0.001 -> 0.00
- -0.001 -> (0.00)

The last one, a very small negative number rounded to zero, is the problem. I still want the brackets to indicate that it was negative.

My first version was a string format as follows:

```
{0:#,##0.00 ;(#,##0.00)}
```

This doesn't work, because it rounds the number before applying the switch on positive/negative, thus deeming that the 0.00 is not negative.

I then tried this, to separate the bracket logic into its own formatting blocks, before and after the number:

```
{0:;(}{0:#,##0.00 ;#,##0.00}{0:;)}
```

Bizarrely, however, this exhibits identical behaviour to the original example. It works correctly for -0.01, but still does not display brackets for -0.001. Somehow the first and last tokens must be picking up on the rounding behaviour of the numerical display token in the middle.

Does anyone have ideas on how to format this so it works how I want?

Comment: Clearly a bug. Does anyone know if this has been fixed in a newer .Net version? (I have .Net 4.0). Does anyone know a workaround that works inside XAML without having to create a dedicated Converter class? And finally, if the bug was fixed, would that create potentially serious backward compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

When you say `;(#,##0.00)` or `{0:;(}`. The value gets already rounded off to 0. Hence it does not get you the result you are expecting.

So it is better to check the sign before it is negative.

```
var value = -0.001M;
string decimalFormat = value > 0 ? "{0:#,##0.00}" : "({0:#,##0.00})";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(decimalFormat, value));
```

Choosing between the string format based on the sign should do.

Comment: Yes, that would work in code, as you specify. Unfortunately my use is in a WPF XAML file, so I am not able to apply the logic as you say - I only have the string format string to play with. I'm still not clear why the {0:;(} token is picking up rounding settings from the completely separate {0:#,##0.00 ;#,##0.00} column either...

Comment: If you are using MVVM pattern this would not be a problem. You should be able to bind this to a property which can modify the format in the property getter of the View Model

Comment: I may end up having to do this. I'm not convinced this logic should be on the view model - it's really a presentation thing. (I also display the negative values in red, again for presentation purposes). Another option would be simply to write a converter class; it's a shame to lose the simplicity of the string format though!

Comment: If you don't want to use MVVM, or you think that it does not belong there, you can always make a custom MultiValueConverter that takes three parameter. #1 is the value. #2 is the first string format. #3 is the second string format.  So just add the logic to that converter, and return the #2 or #3 parameters

Comment: @FrankyB Good one didnt think about it